# Link to original image in a Image Rendition Column

Tags: list, image

I created an Image Rendition Column for a list by following this [blog post](http://www.sharepoint2013.me/Blog/Post/112/Upload-images-to-a-list-with-image-rendition-in-SharePoint-2013).

The list looks great and adding an image is fairly simple.

How can I set this column to link back to the original image?

We set all the images to a height of 75px.  Users would like to be able to click on the image and see the full size version.

Comment: The last screenshot of that blog post shows a "hyperlink" field. Do you not have that? Or are you looking for a more elaborate solution?

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned that I tried adding the hyperlink in that dialog but it still doesn't create a link to the picture

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't find a way to do this with out of the box SharePoint so I wrote some jQuery to do the job:

Create a file named image_link.js and add this to it:

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
 $(".ms-rtestate-field img").each(function() {
    var link = $(this).attr("src")
    link = link.substring(0, link.indexOf('?'));
    $(this).wrap($('<a>',{
        href: link
    }));
  });
});
```

Upload this and jQuery to a document library on the site (Site Assets is a good one). I usually create a folder called js to store JavaScript in.

Next open the view (AllItems.aspx) in SharePoint Designer and add a link to image_link.js at the bottom of the page:

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server">
   <script src="../../../SiteAssets/js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="../../../SiteAssets/js/image_link.js"
   type="text/javascript"></script> 
</asp:Content>
```

Note:  You may have to play around with the ../ in the links above depending on where this list is located